# Play 2.x : Files from conf folder not copied into dist when play dist command used

Tags: playframework-2.0

Say conf/ directory has 
additionally ***.conf file other than the default application.conf.

when using the play dist command, generated dist folder with snapshot doesnot include this.

NOTE : 
start shell script from “play dist” fails to locate the ***.conf file, if I manually unzip and add this file, application works as expected in the distributed version.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new project, and then a `conf/test.conf` and finally doing a "`play dist`" gives me a zip that contains that `test.conf` file, you have any project configuration that might cause your problems?

Comment: Which version of play are you using?